# Spring Boot Maximum Requests and Threads should be 1 (server.tomcat.max-threads=1)

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-webflux

### Background

I am experimenting with Spring Webflux, for reactive applications and I want to see the behavior of the application if I only have one thread in the application.

### Question

How can I make Spring to only use a single thread for all the requests that could come?

So far I set `server.tomcat.max-threads=1`, however I still see that multiple threads are been created per request. You can see some of the logs of the running application below:
[image]

Please let me know if I am missing something I should add in my configurations to make this work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: webflux doesn't use tomcat, so trying to configure tomcat will not work. Also why a single thread **and** webflux, that kind of beats the point.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for responding.
I am just experimenting, like I mention above, I want to see the behavior of Spring Webflux. This is the first time I am using it, so I want to re-search and test everything I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebFlux has nothing to do with Tomcat by default (you can configure WebFlux to use Tomcat/Undertow/Jetty instead of Netty, though). WebFlux uses Netty by default which is not even close to servlets.

In WebFlux all web requests are processed by event-loop, internally it uses reactive Netty to handle the web requests.

The threads for serving the web requests have the name like this:

> reactor-http-nio-4

If you want to configure the number of threads used by event loop, you can do it passing a VM-argument before application startup:

```
-Dreactor.netty.ioWorkerCount=1
```

For example, it would look like this:

```
java -jar application.jar -Dreactor.netty.ioWorkerCount=1
```

---

Also: `parallel-n` threads you can see in your logs are the threads from parallel scheduler, which is used with `Flux.interval()` method. Those are not related to the event loop for serving web requests

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the other answer given which is completely correct.

The threads you see in the logs are just scheduling threads, so they schedule work on the event loop. If you only want one event loop, do as the other answer suggested.

If you on the other hand only want one scheduler you can add `.onSubscribe(Schedulers.single())` on any `Flux/Mono` in the chain.

This will during subscription to your application apply a single threaded scheduler.

Worth noting, this is not what it is meant for, and performance might be extremely crippled.

this single scheduler is mainly used for:

> Optimized for low-latency Runnable one-off executions

according to the [docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html) and is meant for one-shot operations.

Comment: Thanks for adding to the above answer. This information is really useful.